# Highmaps: Show datalabels for only one series

Tags: highcharts

I have a map with three different series of mappoints. I would like to show all the mappoints on the map, but only show the datalabels of one of them initially. Is that possible? I've tried this, but it does not work. The datalabels show up anyway.

```
 {
    // Specify points using lat/lon
    type: 'mappoint',
    name: 'Schuldnerberatung',
    color: '#fabb00',
    visible: true,
    datalabels: {
        enabled: false
        },
    data: [{
        name: 'Gudensberg',
        lat: 51.1770718,
        lon: 9.368258500000024
    },
    {   name: 'Neukirchen',
        lat: 50.86911839999999,
        lon: 9.343763099999933
    },
    {   name: 'Riedstadt',
        lat: 49.8431788,
        lon: 8.467169300000023
    }],
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your options: use `dataLabels` - capital L. In point options you could set it to `true` to show an [individual label](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series%3Cmappoint%3E.data.dataLabels).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tj5rqht1/